# My app only displays "Test Advertisement"

Tags: iad

I am implementing iAds in my app. The view is appearing with an image "Test advertisement". How can I show different ads in the view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you publish the app on the App Store, it will get real ads. The "Test advertisement" ads are there just to allow you to test your implementation when you are developing. So the fact that they appear correctly is a good sign.

To get the revenue from the ads that appear on the published app, you will have to sign the iAds contract that you can find in your iTunes connect account.

---

Note that Apple has algorithms to decide which ads appear in which apps. So you may not get ads even if your app is published and specially if you don't have a large user base.

Comment: My app is published on the App store, but it does not show any add (It shows the test ad in debug mode). More than 1000 users use my app per day! What's wrong with my app?

Comment: @Fa.Shapouri what's the app?

Comment: @Yar It is a universal app, you can find it on appstore by searching "پیمونه"

Answer (score 1):

You don't deliver ads to iAd - the system does it automatically when your app is released.

Ad revenue is also calculated automatically.

Please refer to: [iAd Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/iAd_Guide.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You can get money from apps when they are released.

If you try to launch it from an emulator, you will always see the "Test Advertisement" message.

You will see different advertisements automatically, you don't have to care about it.